# Loop should not run at all, but it runs infinite number of times

Tags: c++

As the size of string is 0 , and 0 <= -1 is false so loop should not run at all, but in this code, it runs infinte number of times. I am not getting the reason. Please help.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string arr[] = {"", "", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz"};
    cout << arr[0].size() << endl; // It gives output 0
    cout << arr[1].size() << endl; // It gives output 0
    // This loop runs infinite number of times, but Why? 
    // As 0 <= -1 is false , so this loop should not run at all.
    for(int i = 0; i <= arr[1].size() - 1; i++) {
        cout << "aaa" << endl;
    }
}
```

In output, it gives infinite loop.

Comment: `string::size()` returns a `size_t` which is an unsigned type. That's why `string.size() - 1` causes an overflow.

Comment: Oh Yes, thank you. I missed the unsigned part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `string::size()` returns a `size_t` type which is an unsigned number. When you subtract 1, you are not getting the value of `-1` but the number `2^64` in a 64-bit architecture.

As you are using an `int` as the counter, its maximum value is `2^31` which is way lower than `2^64`. After `2^31` executions, your counter overflows and becomes a negative number. Thus, making your loop run infinite times.

Comment: Perhaps suggest solutions like `static_cast<>`?